# calculate missing pixel values from edges

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

my sample image looks like this:

```
array([[2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [9, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I want to calculate all missing pixel values which are 0 based on the neighboring pixel values.

Formula to calculate missing pixel value looks like this:

[image: Kernel]

Where DN are values available, X are values sampled by DN and needs to be filled in.

```
X01 = 0.5 DN00 + 0.5 DN02

X10 = 0.5 DN00 + 0.5 DN20

X11 = 0.25 DN00 + 0.25 DN02 + 0.25 DN20 + 0.25 DN22

X12 = 0.5 DN02 + 0.5 DN22

X21 = 0.5 DN20 + 0.5 DN22
```

so far I have tried [convolve2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) on the image with,

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

kernel =  array([[1. , 0.5, 1. ],
                 [0.5, 1. , 0.5],
                 [1. , 0.5, 1. ]])

convolve2d(a, kernel, boundary='wrap', mode='same')
```

but output is not correct:

```
array([[ 2. ,  2. ,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  2.5],
       [ 2. ,  8. ,  2. , 11. ,  3.5, 11. ],
       [ 2. ,  2. ,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  3. ],
       [ 5.5, 16. ,  2.5, 12. ,  3.5, 18. ],
       [ 9. ,  6. ,  3. ,  3. ,  3. ,  6. ],
       [ 5.5, 16. ,  2.5, 11. ,  3. , 17. ]])
```

what am I doing wrong here? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to solve this with an operation that doesn't match your functional definition.  This is not a simple convolution operation; the operation is conditional on the fabric of the window.  With the given `a` array, you want the mean of the non-zero elements.  Why not write your filter that way?

Your given filter mis-handles everything except the spots directly between two non-zero entries: the existing elements shouldn't get changed at all, but the filter cuts them in half; for the "center of four corners" entries, the filter takes full weight for two corners and ignores the others.

---

After OP updated the question:

Much better.  Now, what happens if you change the kernel to specifically handle the case of the four-corners element, as below?

```
kernel = array([[0.25, 0.5, 0.25],
                [0.5 , 1. , 0.5 ],
                [0.25, 0.5, 0.25]])
```

Comment: sorry I had an old kernel in the question. I've updated the question with new kernel.

Comment: great. it works as expected. thanks a lot for the help.